# How to run angular2 cli project in intellij

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

I am developing an Angular2 project generated by angular-cli ( latest ). I want to run everything within Intellij however I can not find a way to do it. Currently I only develop in Intellij but run everything from the console ( 'npm start' ). This is very troublesome however because

1. When I change files the webpack does not always see the changes - I think Intellij is caching the changes or something
2. I can not debug in Intellij only in console of the browser

My question is : How to set up Intellij to do everything that 'npm start' does ( auto compile files and generate maps, watch for changes, serve the files ) so that everything is handled by Intellij and I can use it's full functionality ?

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run Angular application created with angular-cli in IDEA, you have to run `npm start` from [NPM Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.2/npm-tool-window.html) to start the application, create [JavaScript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.2/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) run configuration for http://localhost:4200/ URL and hit **Debug**.

See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/debugging-angular-apps/, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upgjCMHGpwo for more info. See also https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/04/angular-2-workflow-in-webstorm/

Note that you might face issues when debugging on Windows because of recent changes in angular-cli configuration: currently webpack generates absolute Windows paths in sourcemap that break the debugging ([WEB-27381](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27381)). See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-27381#comment=27-2249117 for possible workaround

Comment: "When I change files the webpack does not always see the changes - I think Intellij is caching the changes or something" - angular-cli/webpack still don't correctly handle 'safe writes'. Please try disabling Use "safe write" in File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings

Answer (score 1):

- To debug with Intellij you can use intellij idea plugin for Chrome : "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji"
- to run npm you can use Run | Edit Configuration  | + | npm
- Be aware that on https mode IJ JS debug does not work well.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ is primarily intended for Java development while WebStorm is primarily intended for Web development, particularly Angular, with or without Angular-CLI.

Since you are creating an Angular application with a JetBrains.com tool, you should use the JetBrains.com tool that is specifically targeted to Angular development, which is JetBrains WebStorm, not JetBrains IntelliJ.